# cakePHP single form, two tables, multiple records

Tags: forms, cakephp-1.3, multiple-tables

There are two tables:
`poducts [id, name, etc..]` and `specs [id, product_id, spec_name, spec_value]`,
I'm using a form to edit the product (`/products/edit/332` for example)
In the form i wan to add (it's associated and i can access it in the view) the specs. which are a list of records from the `specs` table.

is it possible to create the specs as inputs in the same form?
also, i would like to enable the feature of "add new spec".

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saving related model data, you can use `saveAll`:

```
$this->Product->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

And your inputs in Product form:

```
echo $form->input('Spec.0.spec_name');
echo $form->input('Spec.0.spec_value');
```

If you need more inputs, just increase the 0 value.

More information: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Comment: three problems: 1) saveAll can save only flat structure of data, multiple records from same model or a single, associated record. 2) the model.number.field_name is great with new records, not with editing them since the id is not present. 3) i'm using cakephp v1.3

Comment: 1) Product and Spec is not hasMany association? 2) My suggestion for update: bring data for specs inputs but when save, delete all specs in beforeSave for saving again since you don't know if the user deleted or added a Spec field in the form. 3) Sorry, I did not see the version before. But the syntax is nearly the same.